# Trying to exclude css and js files with IIRF rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iirf

I'm trying to get IIRF working so that it rewrites certain URLs, but ignores files like `.css` and `.js` files.

I have URLs like:

```
/admin/
/admin/user/
/admin/user/view-details/1
/admin/user/view-details/1?edit
```

Which all work, but I can't seem to get this to work:

```
/admin/_assets/css/admin.css
```

My `.ini` file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule /admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\?edit$ /admin/index.php?edit&action=$1&sub-action=$2&id=$3 [L,I,QSA]
RewriteRule /admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /admin/index.php?edit&action=$1&sub-action=$2&id=$3 [L,I,QSA]
RewriteRule /admin/([^/]+)/$ /admin/index.php?action=$1 [L,I,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ - [L]
```

I've also tried:

```
RewriteRule (.+\.)(php|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|ttf|sql|txt|htm|zip|css)$ - [L]
```

The things I've tried give either a blank document when I navigate directly to the css file, or I get:

```
HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
```

I don't have much experience with IIRF or IIS, so I'm a bit stuck with what to try next. Am I looking in the wrong place? Or have I made a really basic mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Did you place `RewriteRule (.+\.)(php|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|ttf|sql|txt|htm|zip|css)$ - [L]` before the other rules? Did you try to set `RewriteLogLevel` and look at the log file to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes, it's before the other rules, but I'm not getting anything logged in the log file with RewriteLogLevel 3, maybe that's a problem in it's own right.

Comment: It's currently: RewriteLogLevel 3 RewriteLog C:\inetpub\IonicIsapiRw\log.txt - I should add, this was all set up before I got involved, it doesn't look like anything has ever been logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by adding:

```
RewriteRule /admin/_assets/(.+)$ /admin/_assets/$1 [L,I,QSA]
```

to the top of my file. I'm still not sure why nothing is being logged, but this fixed it for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Tip for debugging iirf: use [`StatusUrl`](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf20Help/html/06643ce7-6c93-4d2f-ad3b-01e97fade9ef.htm) to check first for problems.